# RegExp finding a string in a line as long as it is not enclosed by the quotes

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to find a string not enclosed by the quotes. Example:

```
if (myString == System.String.Empty) // RegExp will find System.String
```

but

```
myString = "This is my System.String.Empty String";
```

System.String.Empty will be skipped.

So far I have written the following regexp:

```
(?<!")System\.String(?!(["A-Za-z0-9]))
```

It does catch both cases. What regexp will only catch the first case?

As an explanation for why I need it - I need to rename all of the occurrences of `System.String` to just `string` in the entire code base, but some of our code contains this very string inside quotes.

Comment: `(?!.*".*)System\.String(?!(["A-Za-z0-9]))` ?

Comment: `^[^"]*(System\.String)[^"\r\n]*`

Comment: @MariaDeleva, thank you for your response. Your regex is not using lookahead/lookbehind and is therefore including all of the stuff before the needed string.

Comment: You could look at it from a different angle. Replace all `==\s*System\.String\.Empty` by `== string.Empty` . Because  it's doubtfull that they would use == in the comments.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I changed your lookahead to lookbehind, and it seemed to work, testing it. Please post it as an answer, I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
(?<!.*".*)System\.String(?!(["A-Za-z0-9]))
```

Comment: Note that this won't work in most regex flavour as they only allow fixed-width lookbehind. PCRE is the only flavour I know that would accept this regex.

Comment: @Aaron Hm, investigated further, and indeed it does not find all of the cases. It does find most of them, but those which I expect to be found it skips. Good point..

Comment: @worldpart what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub well, ultimately world domination, but for now I am trying to change all of the valid occurrences of System.String that are not enclosed by the quotes to string. 

E.g.:

System.String.Empty --> string.Empty, but 
"This is my System.String.Empty with some text" should not change

Comment: @worldpart which ide do you use?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub VS2013